# Is there a reliable source of weekly movie box office data?

Tags: data-request, film

I'm attempting to build some analyses and daatavisualisations about movie performance. How do movies compare, for example, on longevity at the box office?

Some public sites such as [BoxOfficeMojo](http://www.boxofficemojo.com) (a part of Amazons IMDB network) have interactive pages with weekly data for many countries, but the data is inconsistent over time (in the UK some older pages only list the top 20 movies not all movies currently showing and there are occasional errors especially in the cumulative box office numbers). And, if you want weekly data you can only view it one week at a time.

Are there any sources where this type of data is available as a bulk download?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the omdb at http://omdbapi.com/
It doesn't download in bulk but you can easily write a script for your choice of titles.